# Prevent Downloading Existing File Again And Again

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

i am working on a simple app in which i am downloading image from URl using Picasso Library.

but i am having problem of downloading the same file again and again. when ever i run this app it downloads same file that is already exists.

it changes name of file but file is always same.

this is my code:

```
package com.example.imagedownloadsample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.squareup.picasso.Callback.EmptyCallback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String currentUrl = "http://8020.photos.jpgmag.com/3456318_294166_528c960558_m.jpg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_download);

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) (findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);

        Picasso.with(this).load(currentUrl).error(R.drawable.error_detail)
                .into(img, new EmptyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        Picasso.with(this).load(currentUrl).into(target);

    }

    private Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 10000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fname = "/Android/data/com.usd.pop/Image-" + n
                            + ".jpg";

                    File file = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + fname);
                    if (file.exists())
                        file.delete();
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                        ostream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
            }
        }
    };

}
```

**i tried this but not working.**

```
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "/Android/data/com.usd.pop/image-" + n
                        + ".jpg";

                File file = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + fname);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: if file exist call break ..dont download and then delete it

Comment: break or return will work...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file.exists())
file.delete();
```

The above condition will always return false, because you are generating random file name every time.

Also, I don't see any code to change `currentUrl`, so even if you run multiple times, same file will get downloaded with a different file name

Comment: then how do i download file as `URL` name instead of `random`

Comment: I didnt understand your requirement correctly. If you want to hit that same URL and delete the old-already-downloaded file, then you can remove that `if` condition, because `FileOutputStream` will overwrite existing file contents.

Comment: actually i want to skip or overwrite existing but i don't know how, so i want to delete existing. or can u tell me how can i save file as same name as URL.

Comment: If you dont want network call to be made if the file is already downloaded, then Picasso will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

**change from this code:**

```
Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "/Android/data/com.usd.pop/image-" + n
                    + ".jpg";

            File file = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + fname);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
```

**to this code:**

```
String fileName = currentUrl.substring(
                        currentUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                        currentUrl.length());

                String fname = "/Android/data/com.usd.pop/image-"
                        + fileName;

                File file = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + fname);
                if (file.exists())
                    file.delete();
```

this will save file as same name as URL file name